# Javascript array variable as property

Tags: javascript, arrays

If I access an array as a property, can I still access its inner indices by saying theArray[index]?

Here's the code I have:

```
function Dictionary() {
    var articles, verbs, nouns, prepositions, adjectives, words;
    articles = ["the", "a"];
    verbs = ["shoot", "break", "amaze", "grope", "destroy", "bark", "stream", "flow"];
    nouns = ["journal", "bird", "library", "book", "calculator", "pen", "evening"];
    prepositions = ["while", "although", "beside", "by", "in", "outside", "like", "into"];
    adjectives = ["white", "black", "blue", "red", "bright", "calm", "cheerful", "clumsy", "cloudy"];
    words = [articles, verbs, nouns, prepositions, adjectives];

    Object.defineProperties(this, {
        "theWords": {
            get: function() {return words;}
        },
        "theArticles": {
            get: function() {return articles;}
        },
        "theVerbs": {
            get: function() {return verbs;}
        },
        "theNouns": {
            get: function() {return nouns;}
        },
        "thePrepositions": {
            get: function() {return prepositions;}
        },
        "theAdjectives": {
            get:function() {return adjectives;}
        }
    });
}
```

In another Javascript function called Poem, I want to access Dictionary's property "theWords". I am doing this by saying something like

```
var theDictionary = new Dictionary();
var articles = theDictionary.theWords[0];
```

Is this possible? Furthermore, can I access the specific indices inside the array "articles" by saying something like:

```
var article1 = theDictionary.theWords[0][0];
```

Is this possible? My code is giving me an error, but I am not sure what is wrong.

Comment: What error is it giving?

Comment: Your code is working for me. Are you using this on an older version of IE (or in compatibility mode on IE)? IE8 brought some support for `Object.defineProperty`, but only with DOM prototypes.

Comment: I also seem to recall being overly stringent in requiring certain items to be explicit in the descriptor, but I could be mistaken. Again, we really need the error here.

Answer (score 0):

This is what I would do:

```
function Dictionary(user){
  /* It's less code to write `var` repeatedly than the variable name twice
     in this case. You can save keystrokes, avoid pressing shift, by using 
     single quotes. That does not mean your code was not clear or didn't work
  */
  this.currentUser = user;
  this.articles = ['the', 'a'];
  this.verbs = ['shoot', 'break', 'amaze', 'grope', 'destroy', 'bark', 'stream', 'flow'];
  this.nouns = ['journal', 'bird', 'library', 'book', 'calculator', 'open', 'evening'];
  this.prepositions = ['while', 'although', 'beside', 'by', 'in', 'outside', 'like', 'into'];
  this.adjectives = ['white', 'black', 'blue', 'red', 'bright', 'calm', 'cheerful', 'clumsy', 'cloudy'];
  this.words = [this.articles, this.verbs, this.nouns, this.prepositions, this.adjectives];
  // you don't really need this function - just an example of a Constructor function
  this.wordsToString = function(){
    var wds = this.words, a = [];
    for(var i in wds){
      a.concat(wds[i])
    }
    return a.join();
  }
}
var dic = new Dictionary('Bob');
console.log(dic.currentUser); console.log(dic.articles[0]);
console.log(dic.wordsToString());
```

Now you can change the `articles` property, or whatever:

```
dic.articles = ['test1', 'test2'];
console.log(dic.wordsToString());
```